# printing with Pointers

Tags: c, pointers, printf

I'm trying to figure out how this code works can someone help me run through the processes going on in here:
Like what does `*(++cp)` mean?
In my mind I'm thinking its = `str + 7`
And `*oddNums` = 1 the start of the oddNums array.
so that `str + 8` after the math which = ld
Sorry I really don't understand it.

```
int main ()
{
    int oddNums[5] = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9};
    char str[20] = "Hello world";
    int *ip = oddNums;
    char *cp = str + 6; 

    printf("\n.%c",*(++cp) + *oddNums);


    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: It needs `#include <stdio.h>` and `#include <stdlib.h>`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
printf("\n.%d",*(++cp) + *oddNums);
```

Break it down. This is equivalent to:

```
++cp;
printf("\n.%d", *cp + *oddNums);
```

The first statement increments `cp` so now `cp == str + 7`. Replacing `cp` in the modified printf yields:

```
printf("\n.%d", *(str + 7) + *oddNums);
```

`*(str + 7)` is the same as `str[7]`, which is the single character `'o'`. `*oddNums` is 1. Performing one final substitution yields:

```
printf("\n.%d", 'o' + 1);
```

It prints the character `'p'`. Or rather, it prints the ASCII value of `'p'`—112—since we have a `%d` format rather than `%c`.

Comment: +1 with (admittedly ridiculous) nitpick: it prints the decimal value of `'o' + 1` in whatever character set the compiler/system happens to use.  ASCII is likely, though.

Comment: Yes it's meant to print the character.  It's meant to be ASCII math.
'o' + 1 = 'p'

Answer (score 3):

```
int oddNums[5] = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9};
```

This creates an array of 5 `int`s. If you refer to `oddNums[2]`, that will give you `5`. If you refer to `oddNums`, that's a pointer to `int` that points to the beginning of the array. So `*oddNums` would give you 1, `*(oddNums+1)` would give you 3, and so on.

```
char str[20] = "Hello world";
```

See my discussion about `oddNums` above, which apply here. This is also a string, which means it ends in a zero after the letter `d`.

```
int *ip = oddNums;
```

Remember `oddNums` is a pointer to an integer. So this just makes a copy of it to another `int` pointer called `ip`.

```
char *cp = str + 6;
```

This assigns the value `(str + 6)` to the `char` pointer `cp`. `str` is a `char` pointer to the string defined above. It points to the beginning of the string "Hello world".

```
printf("\n.%d",*(++cp) + *oddNums);
```

`*(++cp)` means to get what `cp` points to *after* `cp` has been incremented. In other words, *preincrement* `cp`, then get what it points to. `cp` was pointing to `str` + 6, which was the `w` in the string. But `++cp` makes it point to the 'o' in "world". So `*(++cp)` will yield an 'o'.

Then 'o' is getting added to whatever `oddNums` points to. Nothing has happened to `oddNums` since we started, so it still points to the 1 in the integer array. `*oddNums` says "give me what `oddNums` points to", which is 1.

So the value of `*(++cp) + *oddNums` will be `'o' + 1`, which is 'p' (the next letter in the ASCII sequence).

Interestingly, the `printf` says to "print the thing you're given as an integer after you print a line feed and a period" ("\n.%d"). Therefore, the result will be...... `.112`. I think.